# Firebase firestore + Ionic 5

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have a problem with the promise response time. Whenever the function is required, the delay of the promisse causes an error in the code, how do I stop the function until the answer arrives?

Note: when I run 2x, the first comes 'unknown' and in the second, the first answer is in place.

```
info(traz){
    this.cavGlobal.id = traz.id;
    this.cavGlobal.img = traz.img;

     this.firestore.collection('cavaleiros').doc(traz.id).collection('skills').snapshotChanges().subscribe(data2 =>{
       this.items2 = data2.map(e => {
        return  {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          custo: e.payload.doc.data()['custo'],
          img: e.payload.doc.data()['img'],
          level1: e.payload.doc.data()['level1'],
          level2: e.payload.doc.data()['level2'],
          level3: e.payload.doc.data()['level3'],
          level4: e.payload.doc.data()['level4'],
          level5: e.payload.doc.data()['level5'],
          nome: e.payload.doc.data()['nome'],
          texto: e.payload.doc.data()['texto'],
        };
      })
    });


    this.router.navigateByUrl('/cavInfo');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are no promises in the code you've shown here.

`snapshotChanges()` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The subscriber you added here will not get invoked until after the first set of results of query are available.  I will get invoked repeatedly with each new set of changes to the results of the query.  This behavior can't be changed.  JavaScript/TypeScxript code can't be "blocked" to wait for an asynchronous callback.

If you actually did want a promise with the results of the query, you should use `get()` instead of `snapshotChanges()` and use it the way you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).  `get()` will return a promise that behaves just like any other JS promise.